Repairing floating point errors in float column in MSSQL Server
Does anyone have a handy script to correct floating point errors in a float column that has values like:
-0.369999999999999
0.19999999999999
which should be -0.37 and 0.2?  I want to run an UPDATE and then put it into a trigger for this column.

I would ask, is float the right data type in the first place. As you have discovered, a float, cannot store a value like -0.37. Why not use a decimal, and then he problem doesn't exist. Why use a float?

If you want to store exact values use a column type like DECIMAL(10, 2) instead of FLOAT. FLOAT is inherently inexact.

@Thom, It can store -0.37: after I run the script below to repair it, it correctly stores -0.37

How is the column actually declared?  is it FLOAT(size, d), or FLOAT(p)?

In any case, the point is that, internally, it is not actually storing -0.37.  It is storing the binary fraction -0.01011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111010111, which is equal to -3.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875.  If you do it right, after the fact, when you extract/display it, it may round back to 0.37.

float is better than decimal since I also want to be able to store smaller numbers with more decimal places.  float can represent and display -0.37, but only after running the update in the answer.

@Steve, then why would running UPDATE myTable SET Param1 = CAST( CAST(Param1 AS varchar(max)) AS float)  change the display value of SELECT * FROM myTable for that column entry?  after is -0.37, but before the update is -0.3699999999

The question is which kind of data you are storing. For scientific data float is appropriate as this kind of data is inherently imprecise, and the problem is only a display (formatting) problem. For a financial application use decimal.

@Olivier, they are parameter values which can vary how I want them to vary, but I would like to read -0.369999999 as -0.37 since -0.37 is what I saved to the table.

@Steve the column is declared in the create table statement as  Param1 float,

Then format your data when displaying it, e.g. with the format "0.00" (depending on your system). This will round the value to two digits.

@Oliver thanks this may work, but I feel it is not a general solution since only rounding errors at that decimal place would be displayed correctly...  My solution would probably work for e.g. -0.003699999 as well, though I haven't tested this

@Markus I don't know enough about SQL to know why your UPDATE statement seems to "work".  What I do know is that IEEE-754 binary floating-point, which is what float columns probably use internally, is inherently incapable of perfectly representing decimal fractions like 0.37.  It's very good at some things — as you pointed out, being floating-point it can represent both very large and very small numbers — but you never want to get hung up on achieving the exact decimal input you started with, or the exact decimal result you expected.

Rounding appropriately on printout is basically the best and the only thing you can do.  See also the canonical SO question on this topic, Is floating point math broken?

It seems that
SELECT CAST( CAST(Param1 AS varchar(max)) AS float)
 FROM myTable

Will return a float with the precision error removed, where Param1 was a FLOAT to begin with!
So to update all rows:
UPDATE myTable SET Param1 = CAST( CAST(Param1 AS varchar(max)) AS float)


This will not "fix" your issue. A float type cannot accurately store fractional decimal values. the value may look okay when converted to text for display, but when converted back to float, it will still have the original inaccuracy (possibly worse).  That is why SQL has decimal, numeric, and money types.  These are specifically designed to store exact fractional decimal values.

before, running SELECT * FROM myTable would return -0.369999999999999, though the value saved from the client was -0.37.  After running this update, if I run SELECT * FROM myTable, the value displayed is -0.37.  So it seems fixed, since what I wanted was to read -0.37.

Try creating a table with a float, and save -0.37 into it, then select the table to see the value.  It should be -0.37 in the select results, right?  This is what I see when I do it from SSMS, so that is what I would like to see also saving the value -0.37 from a C# Stored proc (where @param1 is float) then selecting the table.

When it comes to binary floating point, stuffing a decimal number into it and expecting to get the same number back out is like translating a word into Japanese and then translating it back into English.  Sometimes you get the same word back, sometimes you don't.  It depends.

@Markus - It appears that you are not comprehending what has been said here. Just like how integers are approximations continuous measurable quantities like degrees C or centimeters of rainfall, floating point numbers are also inexact approximations. This difference is that instead of a resolution of 1, binary floating point numbers might have a resolution of 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, or 1/(2^50). (The actual resolution actually changes with the magnitude of the value.) Notice that one of these resolution steps includes 0.1, 0.01, or 0.001.

Lets say the floating point value had a resolution of 1/8 (3 bits of fraction). The value 0.1 might be stored using the closest supported value 0.125. The value 0.4 might be stored using the closest supported value 0.375. The value 0.5 is a rare exception that is exactly represented. However, 0.2 and 0.3 both share a value 0.25. Extend this logic to fractions having 50+ bits of fractional precision and although you have greater accuracy, the stored values are still approximations.

Take your 0.37 value. That cannot be exactly represented using a float. The closest float representation might be 0.3699999999999999955591 (the digits go on). No amount of manipulation will coax the float to store exactly 0.37. Float simply does not support that exact value. In contrast, the database types decimal, numeric, and money are specifically designed to store exact decimal fractional values. Your best "fix" may be to alter the column definition with ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN param1 NUMERIC(19, 2) or whatever is appropriate for the expected number of digits.

See this db<>fiddle.

One clarification: when @TN wrote "Notice that one of these resolution steps includes 0.1, 0.01, or 0.001", I believe they meant "none of these resolution steps include".
